# Saving a DataFrame with required name

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe as :

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true').load("s3a://" + str(bucket) + '/' + directory_remote + '/' + toName_csv, schema=schema)
```

Now, I want to write this dataframe back into S3 as a csv file with the following folder structure -

```
my-internal-bucket/data/data/datetime=20230515031223/input_file_actual.csv
```

I have tried using the following but not working as per my requirements -

```
csvname = "input_file_actual.csv"
directory_remote = "data"
df.withColumn("datetime", current_timestamp())
df.write.option("header","true").paritionBy("datetime").csv("s3a://" + bucket + '/' + directory_remote +'/' + directory_remote +'/' + csvname )
```

I tried google but couldn't find a suitable answer.
I am new to PySPark. Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot control the name of a file being written out by Spark. You'll have to write it, and then rename it with the API for your file system.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How to create the directory as `/bucket/data/data/datetime=20230515091035` ? Also, the file that will be created will be of random name, right ? How do I tackle it in the code ? Could u share some sample code  ?

Comment: You control the directory name where your file(s) get written in your write command. As far as renaming the file, I know exactly nothing about S3, sorry.